# Keeping track of dynamic navigation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a grid (4x6) which consists of smaller tiles/blocks. 
When someone moves in the grid, I need to keep track of exactly where they moved to. 
So, if I number the tiles

```
 1- 2- 3- 4- 5- 6
 7- 8- 9-10-11-12
13-14-15-16-17-18
```

Now, if i'm at 10, I could move to 4,9,11,0r 16.

How should i keep track of this? What data structure can i use to store this information?

Comment: Do you want to track where the person has been, or where they are able to go?

Comment: Just use a stack. Push to stack after every move.

Comment: Why not use a linked list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Options.

OOP way of doing it:

Create a grid class which contains a 2D array inside. It can be used to create methods such as `surrounding(int x, int y)` which would return the surrounding tiles.

2D array.

Like the OOP way, but a bit messier. You would get surrounding tiles from (x-1, y), (x + 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1).

1D array.

Like you have in your example. This can be a lot harder to use and I would not recommend it. If you did want to use that way, you could have to have another int variable for the 'width' of the grid. In the example provided, it was 6 so the surrounding tiles would be:

(i - 6), (i - 1), (i + 1), (i + 6).

I would highly recommend either the 2D array or Grid option. The Grid, which I prefer is very good if you anal about making things as fancy as possible.